# Errors while creating wordcloud with R

Tags: r, wordcloud2

I am using a following CSV file (written in french) :

```
"1";"Paul is in the kitchen"
"2";"Peter is cooking in the living-room"
"3";"The kitchen is beautiful"
```

And I want to create a wordcloud with wordcloud2 library.

Here is the R script I wrote :

```
 data <- read.csv('file.csv', sep="|",quote="",header=TRUE)
 dim(data)
 library(tm)

 documents <- Corpus(VectorSource(data))
 inspect(documents)

 lapply(documents[1],as.character)
 inspect(documents)

 set.seed(1234)

 tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(documents)
 m <- as.matrix(tdm)
 v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
 d <- data.frame(freq = v)
 d$word=rownames(d)

 library("wordcloud2")
 wordcloud2(d)
```

But I get the following error :

```
> wordcloud2(d)
Error in size * 180/max(dataOut$freq) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What do you think ?

Comment: Try to build `d`with the command `d <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq = v)` and see if it runs.

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! Now I have to understand why I am getting only \"") in the wordcloud ^

Comment: I cannot reproduce the second behavior with the short example you gave use, although the wordcloud I get from it is a little bit silly

Comment: I edited the csv file to make it more realistic... but with this *.csv file, I am getting a wordcloud with only the word "the" (the:1). Is it the expected behavior ? (I was expecting kitchen:2 for instance)

Comment: Not really. I get a good looking wordcloud with your new example if I replace the 4th line with `documents <- Corpus(VectorSource(data$V2))`, because `VectorSource` expects a vector and will behave a little bit strangely if it is given a data-frame.

Comment: I am not sure to undersand what is called "V2"? :( I tried your code but I am getting `> inspect(documents) <<SimpleCorpus>> Metadata:  corpus specific: 1, document level (indexed): 0 Content:  documents: 0 character(0)` and then `> lapply(documents[1],as.character) [[1]] [1] NA`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222356/discussion-between-klaus-and-vincent-guillemot).